# Shared settings in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have 3 files named `appsettings.[int/stg/prod].json`  in my asp.net core app:

```
{
    "EmailForFailedNonCrucial":
    {
        "Email": "royin...",
        "Subject": "...",
        "Body": "...",
        "ConnectionString": "Staging-Connection-String"
    },
    "Servers": [
    {
        "Name": "aaa",
        "Services": [
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "bbb",
        "Services": [
            ...
        ]
    }]
}
```

Each section has a corresponded section in C# class. (for `IOptions`).

I have 3 versions of that file, for each environemnt :

[image]

I can use it via :

```
 public static IConfigurationRoot ConfigureConfiguration()
        {
            return new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($@"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

        }
```

But the *only* thing that should be different across environments is the `ConnectionString`.
The `Servers` section *is the same* for all environments.

**Question:**

It seems odd to duplicate the `Servers` across all 3 files.
How can I accomplish (*inheritance?*) specifying it once, and have only `EmailForFailedNonCrucial` per environment?

Comment: .NET Core Configuration sources override previous entries. You don't need to duplicate files, just specify the new values for each environment. BTW *don't* put `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")` in the string. Not only does it make the code harder to read and understand, you may want to read that value from the *command line*, eg during testing

Comment: What you've written says `Read my settings from a local 'appsettings.json' file, then read another json file and merge or override the new settings, finally merge or override settings pulled from environment variables.` You could add `AddConsole()` to allow you to override settings at runtime too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the heads up( regarding `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`)  , so how would you solve it ?

Comment: Put the common settings in `appsettings.json` and put only *new/overrides* in the environment-specific files. If the `Servers` section is the same for all environments you don't need to repeat it. If you only need to replace *one* setting in there, add only that one. Setting values are a key/value pair, there's no inheritance involved

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was talking about the other comment (_BTW don't put Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") in the string_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration settings in .NET Core are treated as values in a key/value dictionary. Values from multiple providers are all merged together, with newer values replacing the older ones. The file names have no special significance, only the order of the calls matters.

This is explained in [Essential .NET - Configuration in .NET Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632279.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Despite the name, the configuration library is available for Full Framework applications too.

Settings are converted to key/value pairs when loading. This file's contents :

```
{
  "section0": {
    "key0": "value",
    "key1": "value"
  },
  "section1": {
    "key0": "value",
    "key1": "value"
  }
}
```

Are flattened into just 4 pairs, whose keys are :

```
- section0:key0
- section0:key1
- section1:key0
- section1:key1
```

Another file or provider can override a previous setting if it produces the same key. `SomeotherFile.json` could replace `section1:key0` by specifying a new value just for that key :

```
{
  "section1": {
    "key0": "value",
  }
}
```

There's no need to duplicate settings.

You can specify different settings per environment by putting all common settings in one file, and reading environment-specific settings from another file or provider.

```
var envSpecificFile=...
return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile(envSpecificFile, optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
```

Using `appsettings.prod.json` is just a convention. Reading a specific environment variable to determine the environment is just a convention as well.

The common convention for ASP.NET Core projects is to use the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable :

```
var env=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
var envSpecificFile = $"appsettings.{env}.json";
```

The environment could just as easily come from a command-line argument. This would allow testing different configurations on a QA server, eg :

```
string env;
if(args.Length>0)
{
    env=args[0];
}
else
{
    env=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
}
```

The settings don't need to come from a JSON file, they could easily come from a dictionary, a database or a centralized configuration service.

For example:

```
  var dictSettings = new Dictionary<string, string>()
  {
      ["section0:key1"] = args[1],
  };
```

Can be used to override the `section0:key1` value :

```
return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true)
            .AddInMemoryCollection(dictSettings)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
```

That example is a bit contrived. Dictionaries are typically used to provide defaults so they're typically added before other providers.

```
.AddInMemoryCollection(defaultSettings)
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true)
.AddEnvironmentVariables()
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply placing the `servers` section inside your root appsettings.json removing them from your others should add the `servers` configuration to all others by default.

Some more reading : [Configuration in Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)